# git Parameters: Colon vs. Forward Slash

Tags: git

There are some git command parameters that use `:`, some use `/`. For example,

```
# Using /
# `dev` is a branch name
$ git checkout -b dev upstream/dev

# Using :
# `master` is a branch name
$ git push origin HEAD:master
$ git push origin :dev
```

What is the logic to remember when to use `:` vs. `/`, if any?

Comment: Because references can have a slash in them!  eg, `git push origin foo/bar:foo/bar`...

Answer (score 6):

The colon `:` is part of a refspec, which are often used when dealing with remotes, i.e. fetching, pulling, pushing, etc.

As [Nirk points out in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18085344/git-parameters-colon-vs-forward-slash/18085774#18085774), the forward slash `/` is a path separator for references, and is often used to namespace your references.

For example, your local `master` branch is shorthand for the reference `refs/heads/master`, while `origin/master` is shorthand for `refs/remotes/origin/master`. These are actual directory paths that you'll find under your `.git/refs/` folder.

Comment: The only answer which gets to the real differences

Comment: Re. `origin/master`: Instead of "shorthand for `refs/remotes/master`", should it be "shorthand for `refs/remotes/origin/master`"?  On a repo I have handy, `origin/master` and `refs/remotes/origin/master` match, but `refs/remotes/master` gives an "unknown revision" error.

Comment: @cxw you're right; I've edited that in (after coming across this old Q&A)

Answer (score 5):

`:` can also separate a ref from a path for certain commands (but not others). e.g.

```
$ git show HEAD:src/main/Main.scala
```

vs.

```
$ git blame HEAD -- src/main/Main.scala
```

fun fun fun.

Answer (score 4):

The `:` in a refspec separates the source and destination for references:

```
The format of the refspec is an optional +, followed by <src>:<dst>, 
where <src> is the pattern for references on the remote side and <dst> 
is where those references will be written locally. The + tells Git to 
update the reference even if it isn’t a fast-forward.
```

http://git-scm.com/book/ch9-5.html

The `/` is a standard path separator (in this case, the branch `dev` from the remote `upstream`)

Comment: `fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*` It's rather difficult to wrap my head around the fact that `refs/heads/*` denotes something on the remote side and `refs/remotes/origin/*` does local. I thought the `remotes` has something to do with the remote side.

Comment: Siku-Siku, the refs/remote/origin/* refers to the LOCAL paths that are updated with the fetch.  It is confusing because you can use this LOCAL path when referring to the remote branch or tags (ie: `git checkout remotes/origin/branch`). That is why the local path has 'remotes' in it.  The left side of the `:`, referring to the REMOTE path is the path from the perspective of the REMOTE server so the path doesn't have the word remotes because REMOTE sees them as local to itself which is in refs/heads not refs/remotes.  I'm not sure how to say that more concisely.I hope it clears up the confusion.

Comment: @Siku-Siku.Com the whole refspec syntax of `<source>:<desination>` may help. In `fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`, you're fetching from the remote `origin` as the source, so you have to use the path from the perspective of the source, `refs/heads/*`. The destination is your local repo, so you have to use a path from the perspective of the destination, `refs/remotes/origin/*`.

Comment: Thanks James! (+1) I am sure that would help others too. It's never easy to comprehend a notation / term that implicitly contains multiple perspectives. :)