# How to `git log` a tree-ish from another branch?

Tags: git, git-log

Let's say I have a Git repo with branch `A` and branch `B`.
Branch `B` is currently checked out (i.e. `.git/HEAD` contains `refs/heads/B`).
Now, **without checking out branch `A`**, how to view the history (log) of `path/file` in branch `A`?

Following `git help rev-parse`, I've attempted to use `git log A:path/file`, but that doesn't seem to work (outputs nothing). Why?

Comment: `A:path/file` is a shortcut for a name (an identifier) of a specific **tree or blob** object.  For `git log` to follow history you need to start from commit-ish.

Comment: @Jakub, OK, but then, how does `git log path/file` work?

Comment: `git log path/file` is `git log HEAD -- path/file`.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Try this (without the angle brackets):

`git log <branch> -- <path/to/file>`

Comment: Good, this works. Now, explaining in plumbing terms, what's the difference?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the `<branch>:<path>` syntax. I'm just going off of `man git-log`, which offers `git log [<options>] [<revision range>] [[--] <path>...]`. Similarly, mistyping many commands yields this warning from git:

`Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'`

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18085344/git-parameters-colon-vs-forward-slash help answer your question?

Comment: It looks like the colon (`:`) is used to separate two distinct trees (e.g. a remote branch and a local branch), which isn't happening here. You are only examining one branch, and to separate branch from path, you need to use the fairly standard `--`. This provides some explanation: http://git-scm.com/book/ch9-5.html

Comment: Doesn't really help, unfortunately. It is confusing to remember different syntaxes for seemingly the same thing: `git show A:path/file`, bug `git log A -- path/file`?.. `git diff A:path/file B:path/file`, but `git blame A -- path/file`? I have to look this up each time I need it.

Comment: @ulidtko: The mnemonics I use is that `<tree-ish>:<path>` i.e. *one* expression is about *one* object, i.e. tree (directory) or a file, neither of which has history, so it is good for `git show A:path/file`.  `git log <commit> -- <path>` is *two* expressions: history starting from `<commit>` limited to commits that touch `<path>`.  HTH

Comment: Great; been looking for this! Generalizing on this, you can also see the list of all files in that branch with `git log <branch> --name-only` option or see the actual changes with `git log <branch> -p`.