# what is use of ':' in git <branch_name>:<branch_name>

Tags: git, github

I have seen many git commands with syntax like:- `<branch_name>:<branch_name>`
like `git push origin (<branch_name>:<branch_name>)`. What exactly is the meaning of `:` here (why 2 times branch name)? Also, I want to know the difference between `git push origin <branch_name>` and `git push origin <branch_name>:<branch_name>`

Comment: Related, and I think you could find your answer here: [git Parameters: Colon vs. Forward Slash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18085344/4518341)

Comment: The branch on the local repo can have a different name than the branch on the remote.  The syntax is `git push <remote> <local_branch>:<remote_branch>`

Answer (score 2):

With colon notation, a soure and a destination can be defined (`<source>:<destination>`), to

> Specify what destination ref to update with what source object.

See the [git push documentation about refspecs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push?source=post_page---------------------------#Documentation/git-push.txt-ltrefspecgt82308203) and the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7303710/7598462)